# Module not found on SVG files in react

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I have this line of html in my react that keeps giving me this error

> GET http://localhost:3000/icons.svg 404 (Not Found)

```
<svg className="olymp-menu-icon">
    <use xlinkHref="./icons.svg#olymp-menu-icon" />
</svg>
```

And my directory is setup as follows

1. HTML Pages (Main directory)

   - Login.js    (Currently working on this component)
   - icons.svg (Inside same directory as Login.js)

And here is a snippet from my icons.svg

```
<symbol id="olymp-menu-icon" viewBox="0 0 41 32">
<title>menu-icon</title>
<path d="M4.571 0h-4.571v4.571h4.571v-4.571zM9.143 0v4.571h32v-4.571h-32zM13.714 13.714h-13.714v4.571h13.714v-4.571zM18.286 13.714v4.571h4.571v-4.571h-4.571zM27.429 18.286h13.714v-4.571h-13.714v4.571zM0 32h32v-4.569h-32v4.569zM36.571 32h4.571v-4.569h-4.571v4.569z"></path>
</symbol>
```

Comment: Your representation of the directory structure is not entirely clear. Is the `icon.svg` file in the same directory as the HTML page?

Comment: Yes it is. Let me read the formatting tools more

Comment: The relative path between `login.js` and `icons.svg` is immaterial. The relative path must be given between the web address the web page is delivered from (`localhost:3000/`, apparently) and the address the resource can be delivered from. It works the same way as any `<img src>` attribute would work. Or do you have any fancy webpack configuration that inlines svg resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

create-react-app example: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/26f701fd60cece427d0e6c5a0ae98a5c79993640/packages/react-scripts/fixtures/kitchensink/src/features/webpack/SvgComponent.js

```
// in Login.js
import { MenuIcon } from './icons.svg';

// use
<MenuIcon id="icon" />
```

you apply this.

https://github.com/FWeinb/babel-plugin-named-asset-import

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4a87838f527a00be6af42099546ff5d3adf63a6a/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L238-L249

Comment: I tried this, but now I get 'expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.'